# Can I loop a lot of falling objects in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make 7 cubes and I want to auto drop when the game starts. So I use Gravity to make objects fall. When the game start all cubes are dropped automatically but I want to make it happen again and again. I do not have any idea how to make it. So if you know, please tell me how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your cube into a prefab.  Then create a GameObject somewhere in your scene and attach a script to it that spawns the cubes every x seconds.

```
public Transform MyPrefab;
private float timer = 0f;

void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // Spawn a new block every second
    if (timer > 1f) {
        Instantiate(MyPrefab);
        timer -= 1f;
    }
}
```

In the inspector, drag your prefab to the `MyPrefab` property of your spawning object so it knows what to instantiate.

You should probably attach a script to your prefab cubes that calls `Destroy()` on them once they fall completely off screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by attaching a script to falling objects to re-position them after going out of focus of the camera or reaching a specific location on the 3D space.

Some simple scripts like this would do,

```
//Change this to suit your needs
void Update()
{
    if (renderer.IsVisibleFrom(Camera.main))
    { 
         Debug.Log("Still Visible");
    }
    else
    { 
         Debug.Log("Not visible");
         transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

This will not dynamically spawn object nor destroy it would rather reuse existing.

Comment: I use Vuforia ARCamera. I don't have Main Camera and error occurs "UnityEngine.Renderer does not contain definition for 'IsVisibleFrom'". So how can I solve this.

Comment: Use a plane on 3D space to get a threshold, it will be the easiest. Like this, if an object fall below y=100 set its position to y=0.

Comment: or use a trigger collider "offscreen"; cube hits the collider and has it's position reset (lots of ways to do this one :) )